# What can/should be done to mitigate asbestos danger after a disturbance?

Tags: asbestos

I took down the ceiling from an approximately 12x10 foot room to deal with some rodents in the insulation and it turns out that the (painted) popcorn texture on the ceiling contained/contains asbestos.  Mistakes were made, etc.  I already have the material (infested insulation, drywall, texture and all) in contractor bags and under a tarp out of the house.  I guess I'll need someone who deals with hazardous materials to pick them up, but my *actual* question is:

> What do I need to do about the rest of the house?

There was obviously a fair amount of dust involved tearing the ceiling down (though I guess that was mostly gypsum---I didn't scrape the ceiling, just took the drywall down in big slabs).  Is the whole house potentially "contaminated" now?  Is there a way for me to test the level of airborne asbestos (not to test the popcorn texture, but to measure the level of airborne contamination)?  I imagine that there's some correct response between "clean up the area and forget about it" and "abandon the house."

Answer (score 2):

Professional air monitoring is the first step: expect a bill in the range of $500 (a technician stays on site for the entire hour or so test).  A little compressor draws air into a sampling can, which is analyzed in a lab.  They physically look for captured fibers and can find a single fiber in a sample.

Asbestos removal is surprisingly expensive, and must be done by a licensed firm (at least in the USA).  In California USA I was quoted $750 in tipping fee alone for one square foot of asbestos paper, though a bigger firm can combine with other jobs.  Everything is registered and tracked.  As usual get multiple bids: you may have trouble finding a firm willing to clean up after someone else's mess.  The full procedure involves huge quantities of plastic, creating a negative air pressure zone where the worek is done.